# Crystal report viewer doesn't display some fields

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have an array which I filter using Lamda expressions and use it to fill a first datagridView `datagridView 1` on a first form `Form1` then pass its values to a 2nd DatagridView `datagridView2` on a second form `Form2`.

When I load the `DatagridView2` values in Crystal report, the fields are displayed in reverse order and some of them are missing like on the image below. 
[Missing fields in CR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3OMb.png)

The fields are provided from joined tables.

Crystal report page settings: Size = A3 (42 cm X 29,67 cm), orientation = landscape. When I change the page settings the fields are still missing.  I use crystal report for Visual studio 2010 and crystal report 2008.

This CR loading code:

```
try
        {

            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

            ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GUISuiviMmk.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;
            string dir = GUISuiviMmk.Properties.Settings.Default["dirReportFiles"].ToString();

            string aServeur = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1, str.IndexOf(";") - str.IndexOf("=") - 1);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);

            dt = (DataTable)dtgEtat.DataSource;

            string aBaseDonnée = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1, str.IndexOf(";") - str.IndexOf("=") - 1);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);

            string aSecurity = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1, str.IndexOf(";") - str.IndexOf("=") - 1);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);

            string aUser = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1, str.IndexOf(";") - str.IndexOf("=") - 1);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);

            string aPassword = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1 );

            str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GUISuiviMmk.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;

            myConnectionInfo.ServerName = aServeur;
            myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = aBaseDonnée;
            myConnectionInfo.UserID = aUser;
            myConnectionInfo.Password = aPassword;

            String Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, DocRpt);
            report.Load(Path);

            report.SetDatabaseLogon(aUser, aPassword, aServeur, aBaseDonnée);

            report.SetDataSource(dt);
            crViewerEtats.ReportSource = null;
            crViewerEtats.ReportSource = report;
            crViewerEtats.RefreshReport();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Where is the error ?

Comment: are you able to see the missing fields in datagrid2?

Comment: Yes , you can clic on the " Missing fields in CR" link to see them.

Comment: Is it a bug or what ? Need  more information.